# synonym data structure for searching

Tags: java, search, data-structures, lucene, synonym

I'm looking for a data structure to keep synonyms. I would like to keep synonyms in bucket like "North America", "USA", "United States".

Search content can be tagged with any of "North America", "USA", "United States".

```
For example, 
Content_1 is tagged "USA"
Content_2 is tagged "North America"
Content_3 is tagged "United States"
```

If User search for "USA", search result should return all three contents not just Content_1. To do get this, I have to get all synonyms of USA and then do a search.

How can I store synonyms where I look for a one of the synonyms and get all others ?

One way to do this is through HashMap like below

```
USA -> North America,United States
United States -> USA, North America
North America -> USA,United States
```

This one does not look that good. Please suggest a good data structure to store synonyms.

thanks.

Comment: Whats wrong with a Hashmap? What do you mean by "good"? Fast access?

Comment: Access is O(1). But building a data structure looks like generating duplicate items. A better data structure where only one entry is stored.

Comment: Great question. This made me think What search engines like Google might be using.

Comment: How about using a switch like this ?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/SwitchDemo2.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Access is O(1). But building a data structure looks like generating
>   duplicate items. A better data structure where only one entry is
>   stored.

You can use two data structures. One for storing them and one for lookup.
One vector of vectors that contains all the synonyms of a word. And a hashmap that points to the container with all of the synonyms for O(1) lookup.

So you would store your synonyms in a data structure like this (**a list of lists of strings**):

```
{{"USA","North America","United States"},{"Tiny","Small"},{"Great","Good"}}
```

And then you would have a **hashmap**, so if you search for "USA" you will get the first list. If you search for "Small" you will get the second list.

```
"USA"->{"USA","North America","United States"}
"Small"->{"Small","Tiny"}
```

The data in the hashmap is only a reference to the list of synonyms that you saved in the other data structure.

Comment: Didn't get your solution. Can you please elaborate using the example that I took ?

Comment: Then you should make each word as a key and the synonyms become redundant in many values making multiple entries which doesn't make the desired solution

Comment: Those aren't lists. They're sets!

Answer (score 0):

Build a datatype `Synonym` which has a `Set<String>` containing all synonyms for one word (in your case "North America", "USA", "United States").
Then map with a `Map<String, Synonym>` all your words to the corresponding `Synonym`.